# Firebase authentication problem with Apple sign in

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase authentication in a flutter app.

I've set up apple authentication and I'm building for both web and for ios.

In the apple developer console, I have an app id (com.crossology.ios) and an associated services id (com.crossology.auth)

In the firebase console, if I set authentication > apple > services id to "com.crossology.ios", authentication works in my flutter app.

If I set it to "com.crossology.auth", authentication works on my flutter web interface.

I don't see a way to configure apple authentication to work for both web and app at the same time.